# UILabel font size is not correct for bold fonts

Tags: ios, uilabel, uifont

I am dynamically create UIlabels and for the first label I use Bold style.

```
for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.count; ++i) {
    CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(i * (self.frame.size.width / vehicles.count),
                                  3, self.frame.size.width / vehicles.count,
                                  13);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];
    label.textColor = thumbColor;
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.text = vehicles[i].vehicleClass;
    UIFont *labelFont;
    if (i == 0) {
        labelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Next-Bold" size:9.0];
    } else {
        labelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Next" size:9.0];
    }
    label.font = labelFont;

    [vehiclesLabels addObject:label];
    [self addSubview:label];
}
```

But it draw like this

[image]

Why the first label is larger?

Comment: It's very for all the custom fonts.

Comment: Maybe it is a wrong name Avenir Next-Bold?

Comment: code is correct check font name

Comment: The problem is in the name, should be "AvenirNext-Bold". Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For "Avenir Next" family fonts you must use these names:

AvenirNext-MediumItalic,
AvenirNext-Bold,
AvenirNext-UltraLight,
AvenirNext-DemiBold,
AvenirNext-HeavyItalic,
AvenirNext-Heavy,
AvenirNext-Medium,
AvenirNext-Italic,
AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic,
AvenirNext-BoldItalic,
AvenirNext-Regular,
AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic

Change Avenir Next-Bold to AvenirNext-Bold, and Avenir Next to AvenirNext-Regular

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to change the below line of code.

```
labelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNextCondensed-Bold" size:9.0];
```

For all of the font family name checking use following code for that.

```
NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
    NSArray *fontNames;
    NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
    for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
    {
        NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
        fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                     [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
                      [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
        for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
        {
            NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces from the font name it will works for you

```
UIFont *labelFont;
    if (i == 0) {
        labelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Bold" size:9.0];
    } else {
        labelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Regular" size:9.0];
    }
    label.font = labelFont;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code the font is not applied to first string in that array. If you try to print the log for labelfont it will be nil for i=0.
And if you print the log for label.font you could see the following output

```
(lldb) po label.font
<UICTFont: 0x7fbbb36185a0> font-family: ".SFUIText-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt
```

For the bold font to be working please try the following,

```
labelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Bold" size:9.0];
```

Hope this will help.